# How to get the actual value of a field in Views?

Tags: 7, views, entities

I'm using the Views module and Drupal 7 and want to add a class to all rows of my table that have a certain value for a certain field.

The field is a bit field and is included in my query. I have added a PHP field (a separate Views module that is installed) with the following code:

```
if ($row->field_kampioen || $row->field_spirit) {
    return 'views-table-highlight';
} else {
    return '';
}
```

This should allow me to set the row class to `[php]`. This works, but all rows get the css class. When I output this for debugging:

```
return $row->field_champion . ' ' . $row->field_spirit . ' ';
```

I see that the classes are all different numbers, and `field_champion` is equal to `field_spirit`. This makes me think I'm seeing the ID.

How can I get a `TRUE` of `FALSE`? So, how can I get the actual bit value of this field?

It would be nice if I could do this via the Views module only, but I've seen pages where hooks are used. Maybe I'll have to use that.

Comment: are you using drupal 6 or 7?

Comment: Sorry. Drupal 7. I updated my question.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you are using Drupal 6, since you mentioned about PHP filed.

below is the code to retrieve value from a field and where ['tid_1'] is the token for a field. I think this is similar for Drupal 7 too.

```
<?php     
$static = $this->view->display_handler->get_handlers('field');    

$b=$static['tid_1']->last_render; //$b contains the value of the field
$d=$static['tid_2']->last_render; //$d contains the value of the field   
//use your logic
 ?>
```

Comment: Is it possible this method (`last_render`) no longer exists? I know I have an object of type `views_handler_field_field` because I tried using it as an array and got a error stating I couldn't use this type as an array. But `last_render` doesn't give me anything. [Other methods](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/modules!field!views_handler_field_field.inc/class/views_handler_field_field/7) I found give me nothing or the wrong value (for example `get_field` gives me the name of the field, i.e. 'field-spirit-value').

Comment: @Peter i will check this in d7 tommrow.